# JQuery getJson success function is firing on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp, getjson

I'm having trouble getting getjson success event to fire. When I'm calling $.getJSON on $(document).ready its working fine and when I put the same code under button click then it is not working.

**Working Fine(under $(document).ready)**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>API Logger</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function(){
                var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
                $.getJSON( flickerAPI, 
                {
                    tags: "mount everest",
                    tagmode: "any",
                    format: "json"
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    alert("success");

                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <button id="btn1" >Execute</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

**Not Working (under $('#btn1').on('click', function()**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>API Logger</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
        "use strict";
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btn1').on('click', function() {

                var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
                $.getJSON( flickerAPI, 
                {
                    tags: "mount everest",
                    tagmode: "any",
                    format: "json"
                },
                function(data)
                {
                    alert("success");

                });

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <button id="btn1" >Execute</button>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't work becuase you put your button in form

```
<form>
    <button id="btn1" >Execute</button>
</form>
```

It'll submit evertime you click in other sense it'll reload the page.

Just define type of button inside the form.

Try like this

```
<form>
    <button type="button" id="btn1" >Execute</button>
</form>
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s3nvqL2o/)**</kbd>

Or just add return false in click event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn1').on('click', function () {
        var flickerAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON(flickerAPI, {
            tags: "mount everest",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        }, function (data) {
            alert("success");
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s3nvqL2o/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: its Working fine now, Thanks